# MySql - FIND_IN_SET check if all exist

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check in mysql if all given keys exists in set or not. like:

```
    $comma_separted_user_ids = "20,2,9,8,31,1";

    $query ="SELECT conversation_id FROM message 
             WHERE FIND_IN_SET($comma_separted_user_ids, user_ids) ";

    // data of user_ids = "1,2,8,9,20,31";
```

I want to check if all user id exist in `user_ids` column or not, `user_ids` are not properly ordered.

Please suggest a solution, thanks.

Comment: correct would be `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(needle, haystack)` and you've got to use nice AND conditions.

Comment: Oh sorry that was writing mistake, I have corrected it.

Comment: Yet another example of difficult, highly inefficient query on coma-separated values (see also: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/1446005))

Comment: are you trying to compare a comma separated list to a comma separated list??

Comment: yes, but they are not ordered. I want to check if all ids exist in column value.

Comment: @user007 im sorry but find_in_set does not compare two CSL (comma separated lists) together.. it compares one value with a comma separated list.

Comment: @JohnRuddell OK, I create a relationship table, as per suggested in below answers. thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is technically feasible:

```
$query = 
  'SELECT conversation_id FROM message'
  . 'WHERE FIND_IN_SET(' 
  . str_replace(
      ',',
      ', user_ids) AND FIND_IN_SET('
      $comma_separted_user_ids
  )
  . ', user_ids)' ;
```

... **you should never do this!**

Instead, create a new table to model the many-to-many relationship that exists between your `user` and `message` entities (e.g. `participant`). This is [basic normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Then the query becomes trivial *and* performant:

```
SELECT conversation_id FROM participant
WHERE user_id IN ($comma_separted_user_ids)
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(user_id) = [number of items in $comma_separted_user_ids]
```

Comment: Your solution is working good, but I will create a new relation table as per you guys suggested. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know the ordering, I don't see a way around FIND_IN_SET. Like [others said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25187677/316310), it'd be far better to normalise your table structure.

But in the interest of providing an answer to the question, you'll need to create a list of `FIND_IN_SET` operators.

```
// A list of IDs.
$comma_separated_user_ids = "20,2,9,8,31,1";

// The TRUE string will make sure that the array 
// always contains at least one item.
$where = array("TRUE");

// Iterate over the IDs and create strings such as
// "FIND_IN_SET(1, column_name_here)"
foreach(explode(",", $comma_separated_user_ids) as $id) {
    $where[] = "FIND_IN_SET($id, user_ids)";
}
```

Then it's a simple matter of joining the strings together:

```
// Join everything together with AND (&&).
// Since "0" is considered FALSE, this works.
$where = implode(" && ", $where);

// Query for rows.
$query ="SELECT conversation_id FROM message WHERE ($where) ";
```

Don't use this if you don't need to. It won't scale very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
SELECT conversation_id
FROM message 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET($comma_separted_user_ids, user_ids) > 0
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING count(distinct user_id) = 1 + (length($comma_separted_user_id) - length(replace($comma_separted_user_id, ',', '')))
```

The `having` clause is counting the number of elements in the comma separated list.

If you are creating the SQL, you should consider using a table to store the values instead of a list.  A `join` approach can take advantage of indexes, which `find_in_set()` cannot.

Answer (score -1):

i guess you should write it like this :

```
$comma_separted_user_ids = "20,2,9,8,31,1";

    $query ="SELECT conversation_id FROM message 
             WHERE user_id IN ($comma_separted_user_ids) ";
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question the user asked. (I'm just leaving a comment, I didn't downvote this answer.) The pattern in this answer is the normal pattern we'd see with a normalized data model. I believe that OP has a different problem: the "comma separated list" stored in a VARCHAR column, an all-too-familiar SQL  anti-pattern.